# How to estimate the number of elements inserted to a Bloom filter

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, bloom-filters

A [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) is a probabilistic data structure that allows encoding sets with false positives.

Parameterized by the number of bits $m$ in the array $A$ (initialized to zeros), and number of hash functions $k$, an insertion of an item $x$ corresponds to setting $A[h_i(x)]=1$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$.

Similarly, for testing if an item $x$ was inserted, we return True iff $\forall i\in[k]:A[h_i(x)]=1$.

> **Given a Bloom filter $A$ (and denote the number of hash functions by $k$), how can we estimate the number of elements added to the set so far?**

---

If $k=1$, estimating the number of elements corresponds to the [Linear Counting](http://dblab.kaist.ac.kr/Prof/pdf/ACM90_TODS_v15n2.pdf) algorithm. What can we do for a larger $k$?

---

One possible way seems to invoke the Linear Counting estimator and divide it by $k$. Can we do any better?